# Troubleshooting bottle neck in pyserial with profile

Tags: python, tkinter, pyserial

I want to be able to read in serial data as close to real-time as possible. Real time for my application is a new string of data received every 20 milliseconds. In the following format:

285,285>0,0>7,8|315,315>30,30>7,8|345,345>60,60>7,8|375,375>90,90>7,8

the numbers may vary I'm using a potentiometer hooked up to an arduino that sends this data over every 20ms to simulate my sensor at a max baud of 250000.

My tkinter GUI that I have made to read this data can't read this at anyhwere near the speed that it is receiving data at. In order to show that here is the result of waiting for 1200 data points. (If reading at the ideal speed this would be done with an average read time of 20ms per value and an overall time of 24 seconds)

Here are the results: 
Average Read time: 0.0439025016626
total time: 68.7999999523

And In order to find the bottle neck I was told that i should profile the code. So here is the data that comes from profiling the code:(I havent been able to figure out how to improve it)

```
Ordered by: standard name

ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
    79    0.001    0.000    0.002    0.000 __init__.py:49(create_string_buffer)
     1    0.000    0.000    0.081    0.081 just_read.py:79(readData)
    79    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 serialutil.py:404(getTimeout)
     1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 serialwin32.py:234(inWaiting)
    79    0.078    0.001    0.080    0.001 serialwin32.py:242(read)
   476    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {_ctypes.byref}
   158    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {isinstance}
    27    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'append' of 'list' objects}
     1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
     1    0.001    0.001    0.081    0.081 {method 'readline' of '_io._IOBase' objects}
    17    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'split' of 'str' objects}
     1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'strip' of 'str' objects}
     2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {time.time}


      922 function calls in 0.082 seconds
```

and lastly here is the code I am using for the GUI:

```
import Tkinter
import serial
from collections import deque
import random
import time
import cProfile
import profile

class App:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.arduinoData = serial.Serial('com5', 250000, timeout=None)

        frame = Tkinter.Frame(master)

        self.go = 0

        self.run = Tkinter.LabelFrame(frame, text="Testing", borderwidth=10, relief=Tkinter.GROOVE, padx=10, pady=10)
        self.run.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=20, pady=20)

        self.run_respiration = Tkinter.Button(self.run, text="RUN",bd=10, height=5, width=10, command=self.getData)
        self.run_respiration.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)

        self.test_options = Tkinter.LabelFrame(frame, text="Test Options", borderwidth=10, relief=Tkinter.GROOVE, padx=10, pady=10 )
        self.test_options.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=20, pady=20)

        self.stop = Tkinter.Button(self.test_options, text="STOP", bd=10, height=5, width=10, command=self.stopTest)
        self.stop.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)


        frame.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=20, pady=20)

    def do_cprofile(func):
        def profiled_func(*args, **kwargs):
            profile = cProfile.Profile()
            try:
                profile.enable()
                result = func(*args, **kwargs)
                profile.disable()
                return result
            finally:
                profile.print_stats()
        return profiled_func

    def getData(self):
        return self.start()


    def stopTest(self):
        self.arduinoData.write("<H>")
        self.go = 0

    def start(self):
        self.arduinoData.write("<L>")
        self.go = 1
        self.xdata = []
        self.pressure1 = []
        self.displacement1 = []
        self.cycle1 = []
        self.pressure2 = []
        self.displacement2 = []
        self.cycle2 = []
        self.pressure3 = []
        self.displacement3 = []
        self.cycle3 = []
        self.pressure4 = []
        self.displacement4 = []
        self.cycle4 = []
        self.k = 0
        self.h= 0
        self.timed = []
        self.limit = 2400
        self.t = time.time()
        self.timer()

    #@do_cprofile
    def readData(self):
        if (self.arduinoData.inWaiting()>8):
            j = time.time()
            x = self.arduinoData.readline()
            z = time.time()-j
            self.timed.append(z)
            self.xdata.append(self.k)
            self.xdata.append(self.k+1)
            strip_data = x.strip()
            split_data = x.split("|")
            actuator1 = split_data[0].split(">")
            actuator2 = split_data[1].split(">")
            actuator3 = split_data[2].split(">")
            actuator4 = split_data[3].split(">")
            p1 = actuator1[0].split(",")
            p2 = actuator2[0].split(",")
            p3 = actuator3[0].split(",")
            p4 = actuator4[0].split(",")
            d1 = actuator1[1].split(",")
            d2 = actuator2[1].split(",")
            d3 = actuator3[1].split(",")
            d4 = actuator4[1].split(",")
            c1 = actuator1[2].split(",")
            c2 = actuator2[2].split(",")
            c3 = actuator3[2].split(",")
            c4 = actuator4[2].split(",")
            self.pressure1.append(int(p1[0]))
            self.pressure1.append(int(p1[1]))
            self.displacement1.append(int(d1[0]))
            self.displacement1.append(int(d1[1]))
            self.cycle1.append(int(c1[0]))
            self.cycle1.append(int(c1[1]))
            self.pressure2.append(int(p2[0]))
            self.pressure2.append(int(p2[1]))
            self.displacement2.append(int(d2[0]))
            self.displacement2.append(int(d2[1]))
            self.cycle2.append(int(c2[0]))
            self.cycle2.append(int(c2[1]))
            self.pressure3.append(int(p3[0]))
            self.pressure3.append(int(p3[1]))
            self.displacement3.append(int(d3[0]))
            self.displacement3.append(int(d3[1]))
            self.cycle3.append(int(c3[0]))
            self.cycle3.append(int(c3[1]))
            self.pressure4.append(int(p4[0]))
            self.pressure4.append(int(p4[1]))
            self.displacement4.append(int(d4[0]))
            self.displacement4.append(int(d4[1]))
            self.cycle4.append(int(c4[0]))
            self.cycle4.append(int(c4[1]))
            self.h += 1
            self.k += 2
            if self.k >= self.limit:
                self.go = 0
                avtime = 0
                for u in self.timed:
                    avtime += u
                avgtime = avtime/self.limit
                print avgtime
                print str(time.time()-self.t)



    def timer(self):
        if self.go == 1:
            self.readData()
            root.after(10, self.timer)

root = Tkinter.Tk()
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Is there a faster data type to receive? Is there a better approach (I'm sure that this is the case as I am a novice)?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Have you tried running the code without tkinter? You've got what appears to be an artificial 10ms delay after every read. If the reading takes .02 and then you add .01 of wait time, that's overall .03 per read.  Instead of reading one line, wait 10ms, read one line, wait 10ms, etc., have you considered reading in blocks of perhaps 20 or more lines at a time?

Comment: I need to use Tkinter or another GUI in order to run the tests that i need to run. I just put the relevant info because I didn't want to bloat the question. I am using the data for graphing purposes in the Tkinter window in the full GUI but I have found that the most limiting step is the reading of the data so I thought that i would go about trying to solve that first. @BryanOakley

Comment: My point was, remove as much of the GUI as possible to help narrow down the problem. Does the code run at high speed if you have no GUI? If so, then the problem is definitely the GUI. If it still runs slow without the GUI, then it's definitely not the GUI. Also, I suggest trying to read in chunks rather than one line at a time with a 10ms delay.

Comment: How would you suggest reading in the blocks. I ran it without the GUI in a while loop and there was some performance increase: The average read time went down to .0460883335272 seconds and the total time was 55.3519999981 seconds @BryanOakley

Comment: There's nothing special you need to do. Just put the reads in a loop, and either exit the loop after a certain amount of time has elapsed (200ms is a good time between UI updates without the user noticing), or after a certain number of records have been read.  Though, it sounds like even without changes to the GUI, there are non-tkinter related performance problems.

Comment: Do you have an idea of the Non Tkinter related problems that I may be able to fix @BryanOakley I added a block of reads and like you said that does work much better